# Parsing HTML and storing in java collection

Tags: java, html, collections

I have a requirement where I have to parse an HTML page that contains multiple tables of scorecard. table structure remains same but based on data for different matches,different tables can contain different, though column names are same.
Now i need to search based on table columnname and data contained in it with an argument pair. e.g. if i have a column called playername and multiple tables contain many player names. if i search for a particular player name by passing 2 arguments- playername(column name) and Jason, it should fetch all rows where playername column has Jason as its data. i can pass another pair of arguments as a AND - matchesplayed(column name) and 15, it should fetch all rows from above result set where Jason played 15 matches.
Can you assist how I can achieve this. Logic I tried is-
get the data for all columns in different array lists.then create a map with the column names as keys and its values as different arraylists containing that column's data. Is my approach correct or i need to solve it using different approach.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't try to parse html with regexes/substrings/indexOf's. Use http://www.jsoup.org

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jsoup to get the HTML Document and then write a method with the input player name values. This method should parse through `<table>` elements in the html document to get you what is needed. Parsing will be easy if you understand Jquery/css selectors.

Check this link for Jsoup Selectors.
http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html

Comment: Thanks KRam. i am using Jsoup. But dont know how can i map column name and value to find matched records and then on top that if i have another argument pair of column name and value, how can i select subset from earlier returned result set.

Comment: You can search for the <Table> > <td> value to search for the required value.

Comment: You can search for the <Table> > <td> value to search for the required value.

Elements values = doc.select("Your CSS Selector"); 
The CSS selector can easily be got from Chrome's developer console

Answer (score 0):

Let's make order. I use your example.

1) The first thing you have to do is searching for rows where playername == Jason. Using jsoup or another HTML parser you can easily have access to the `td` where Jason is contained in. From there, you can easily access to the parend `tr`and to the `table`.

2) Using the `table` you can access first `tr` or `th` to individuate columnname to use as keys. Then using a positional logic (first with first, second with second) you can understand which columnname corresponds to which content (inside the `td`

3) How to collect data is up to you. Probably, a `Map<String, String>` can be a solution. Or, if data is static, you can create a `Player` pojo and use reflection api to fill it.

Giving us more details and snippets of code we can help you more.